# kallsyms_lookup_name for a per_cpu variable

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to retrieve a kernel symbol of a variable by name. The variable is defined as per_cpu. How can I use kallsyms_lookup_name to retrieve it?

Comment: is the variable in user space or in kernel space  ?

Comment: That variable is in kernel space

Comment: What issue is `kallsyms_lookup_name` throwing at you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. how can I get per CPU ptr?

Comment: Please look up on how to you `kallsyms_lookup_name`. Just by passing the name of the concerned variable to this function you will get address of that variable in return.

Comment: The variable is defined with "DEFINE_PER_CPU", How can I get the variable of a specific cpu (say cpu 4)?

Comment: Can you throw more light on the issue like what the variable is if it is a kernel's variable and not the one added up by you and what is it for and where to find it. Add these to your question it self.

Answer (score 2):

For the short answer, you can access per-cpu variables using `kallsyms_lookup_name` carefully along with the `get_cpu_ptr` API.

For the long answer, we have to understand that accessing APIs via `kallsyms_lookup_name` subverts API stability of our kernel module. It will likely to break for future kernels, and it is not guarantee that future kernels will even have the `kallsyms_lookup_name` function accessible.

Now, for how this can be done -

Suppose we have the following per-cpu variable declared in a header file:

```c
DECLARE_PER_CPU(struct tick_sched, tick_cpu_sched);
```

The kernel's implementation of per-cpu has a different meaning for the address of `tick_cpu_sched`, that is `&tick_cpu_sched`. It is the offset inside the per-cpu section, and not an absolute address. When we call `kallsym_lookup_name` on it, we don't receive a valid address that can be dereferenced like usually happens, but an offset that masquerades as a pointer. The standard per-cpu APIs that assume `&<var>` is the offset won't work, but we can use a lower level API `get_cpu_ptr`.

So let's use `kallsyms_lookup_name` in the init function of our kernel module:

```c
struct tick_sched *PER_CPU_tick_cpu_sched = 
     (struct tick_sched *)kallsyms_lookup_name("tick_cpu_sched");
```

I named this `PER_CPU_tick_cpu_sched` to alarm ourselves from accessing it directly.

We can now use the `get_cpu_ptr` API to access this per-cpu variable:

```c
struct tick_sched *tick_sched = get_cpu_ptr(PER_CPU_tick_cpu_sched);
/* Access tick_sched here */
put_cpu_ptr(tick_sched);
```